# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3\pi}}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{3\pi}}\cos 7x^2\;dxdy$?

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral by reversing the order of integration:

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{3\pi}}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{3\pi}}\cos 7x^2\;dxdy.$$

I have tried a lot of times, but I did'n get something reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}
\int_{y}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}\cos\pars{7x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
=
\left.\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}\cos\pars{7x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\right\vert_{x\ >\ y}
\\[3mm]&=
\left.\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}\cos\pars{7x^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\right\vert_{y\ <\ x}
=
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}\cos\pars{7x^{2}}\,
\int_{0}^{x}\dd y\,\dd x
=
\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}3\pi}}\cos\pars{7x^{2}}x\,\dd x
\end{align}

Now, OP can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To properly integrate this, you must change the order of integration from $dx\,dy$ to $dy\,dx$.  To do this, try sketching the region; you then need to come up with inequalities of the form $a\leq x\leq b$ and $f(x)\leq y\leq g(x)$ to describe the region.

Comment: I get 0 ≤ x ≤ Sqrt(3pi) and x ≤ y ≤ Sqrt(3pi), but I am not sure if I'm right. Are those two the right inequalities?

Comment: @user2013804 No!  Remember, you started with $y\leq x$... so, it better not be the case that $x\leq y$ now!  Seriously, try sketching the region. It makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Integration domain is the triangle $T=\{(x,\;y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon\;\;0\leqslant {y}\leqslant {\sqrt{3\pi}},\;\;y\leqslant{x}\leqslant {\sqrt{3\pi}}\} $ under the diagonal of the square $S=\{(x,\;y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon\;\;0\leqslant{x}\leqslant {\sqrt{3\pi}}, \;\; 0\leqslant {y}\leqslant {\sqrt{3\pi}}\}.$Changing the order of integration, we have
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{3\pi}}\int\limits_{y}^{\sqrt{3\pi}}{\cos{7x^2}dxdy}=\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{3\pi}}\left(\int\limits_{0}^{x}{\cos{7x^2}dy}\right)dx.$$
Can you proceed now?

Comment: Is the answer 0? This is what i get, but I am not sure if it is right.

Comment: @user2013804 The first question is, what do you get for the inner integral?  Then you should be able to make a substitution and find the outer integral.